# How is Space-Time curved inside an object?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

I have read explanations about how space-time is curved outside an object. I have also read about the rotational frame-dragging and linear frame-dragging effects of moving objects on the spacetime fabric. However, I was curious about the properties of space-time inside an object (e.g. Earth). I could not find information about this. (P.S. I do not have a degree in physics, just curious.)

Could someone explain how to think about space-time within a mass?

Is the outer mass ignored if we are at some point inside the mass as in Newtonian physics?

Comment: Look at the field equations, in the vacuum surrounding a mass you solve the field equations in vacuum, $R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=0$, when there is mass-energy present in the region you are considering the energy momentum tensor in the field equations will be non-zero.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_Schwarzschild_metric

Comment: @G.Smith Thanks! That was informative. So, intuitively speaking, does the curvature reduce to zero at the center? Does the curvature all around the center not affect the center in any way?

Comment: I haven’t computed the Riemann tensor for this metric. The Einstein tensor is not zero at the center, because the energy-momentum-stress tensor isn’t zero there. You cannot talk about *the* curvature in GR. The Riemann tensor has 20 independent components!